# How can I convert a model's UVs so that they fit within the texture boundaries, but keep the tiling effect that they had?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a model that takes advantage of UV repeating i.e. UVs technically go outside image bounds, but it just means that the texture is repeated. The engine I am working with doesn't allow this. How can I convert these UVs so that they fit the image bounds but keep the tiling?

I can't use nodes to solve my problem since it doesn't actually restructure the UV mappings.

Comment: You could bake the texture and save a new image.

Comment: Or you could tile the texture in Photoshop or another image editing software so it's already tiled within the UV bounds.

Comment: Can you share the model and the texture? Upload it to https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

This node setup can repeat the texture, but be aware, you have adapt the values for your needs. It depends on the texture size.

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you use mapping node to repeat the textures? Is there something wrong with using that?

Comment: There are always different ways to solve problems. Nope, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use nodes to solve my problem since it doesn't actually restructure the UV mappings. I need to get the actual UVs all within the image bounds because that is what the engine requires.

Comment: so you should have written this in your question - this is what a good question is about: it tells what it wants and what it doesn't want...i cannot smell what your engine requires...